# JSON data not reaching view pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to build a page where when the user presses a button a variable which initially is 0 increments with 1. This number is then sent asynchronously to the server by using jQuery AJAX.

What I have so far is:

In my `__init__.py` file:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):

    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')

    DBSession.configure(bind = engine)

    Base.metadata.bind = engine

    config = Configurator(settings = settings)

    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')

    config.add_static_view('static', 'static')

    config.add_static_view('scripts', 'scripts')

    # Removed the other views

    config.add_route("declare_usage", '/user/{user_id}/{address_id}/declare')

    config.add_route("declare_usage_json",'/user/{user_id}/{address_id}/declare.json')

    config.scan()
```

My HTML + Jinja2:

```
#Removed code for simplicity

<div id="button_add">Add</div>

{{val}}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var room = 0;

    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',

                 url: '/user/1/5/declare', #I use a direct user ID and a direct address ID as I'm not sure how to send this to JS from Pyramid ... yet :).

                 data: JSON.stringify(room), 

                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});



    $('#button_add').click(function(){

        room = room + 1;

    });

});
```

My view code:

```
@view_config(route_name = 'declare_usage', renderer = 'declara.jinja2')
@view_config(route_name = 'declare_usage_json', renderer = 'json')
def declara_consum(request):

#Removed code for simplicity

    val = request.POST.get('room') #I get a "None value in my html" if I change to request.json_body -> I get an error that there is no json to be parsed.

    return { 'val' : val }
```

What happens is that when I open the debugger the POST request is successful with no data and on the page I get 2 options for 'val':

1. `None` -> When I use val = request.POST.get('room')
2. Error `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` -> When I use val = request.json_body

Also, still can't get it to work if in my JS i change url to be `/user/1/5/declare.json` and/or data to `{'room' : room}`

Can somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need another route `declare_usage_json`, just need separate two function like this

```
@view_config(route_name = 'declare_usage', renderer = 'declara.jinja2')
def declara_consum(request):
    # this will response to your jinja2
    return { 'val' : val }


@view_config(route_name = 'declare_usage', xhr=True, renderer = 'json')
def declara_consum_ajax(request):
    # this will response to your asynchronously request
    val = request.POST.get('room')
    return { 'val' : val }
```

when you send a request using ajax, this will goto the second function.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/user/1/5/declare',
        data: {'room' : room},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response){
        // update your data at html
    });
```

Comment: Now from my jinja2 view I get an error stating that "val" is not defined. In my debugger under the POST request I can see the value being sent to the server. It's just not rendered in my jinja2. I need a way to share this data between these 2 renderers.

Comment: where the value from, from database? then you can query your `value` from database and return to your jinja2, then get and update value from ajax view function